# TagLib - Getting GEOB Content

Tags: c++, taglib, id3v2

Using TagLib::File::properties(), some common tags such as GEOB are ignored though they are within IDv2.3 spec.

My question is, when using TagLib::File, how can you get GEOB data as well as it's content formatted for it's mime type? For this specific example I have a GEOB with "application/octet-stream".

Would the correct approach be to use the codec specific classes to find a GEOB frame, then parse over the GEOB data? GEOB has a standard format of data, TagLib should support this but I see no example of it.

This question specifically is asking for an example of how to get GEOB frames and it's data for any file type passed to it (Supporting ID3v2 or not, as FLAC sometimes has ID3v2 frames).

Answer (score 0):

TagLib supports the `GEOB` frame directly.  The docs are [here](http://taglib.org/api/classTagLib_1_1ID3v2_1_1GeneralEncapsulatedObjectFrame.html).  The `properties` method is primarily for text properties, which doesn't apply to binary frames like `GEOB`.  You'll need to use the [MP3](http://taglib.org/api/classTagLib_1_1MPEG_1_1File.html) and [ID3v2](http://taglib.org/api/classTagLib_1_1ID3v2_1_1Frame.html) APIs directly.